# jQuery Ajax Request - Lose Method

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a page index.php that uses a modal to upload files. After those have uploaded I use the following to update my database and load in the new images to a list.

```
$('#sortableImages').load('../includes/sortImages.php?edit=' + edit);
```

Executes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(function() {
        $("#sortableImages ul").sortable({ 
            opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
                $.post("../albumUploader/queries/sort.php", order);
            }
         });
    });

});
</script>
echo "<ul class='revisionList'>";

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $sortImageName = $row['OrgImageName']; 
                    $sortPath = "../data/gallery/" . $getGalleryID . "/images/album/" . $sortImageName;
                    echo "<li class='sortPhotos' id='recordsArray_{$row['id']}' >";
                    echo '<img src="'. $sortPath .'"/>';
                    echo "</li>";
                }

                echo "</ul>";
```

The images populate in a div #sortableImages on the index page. However it seems that I lose my method of sortable() from the js file that was originally loaded in the index.php or after the ajax request it's not reading the js. What am I missing here?

Thanks a million.

Comment: what do you mean by lose? "it's not reading the js," please clarify.

Comment: correct, sorry little 'loose' with my terminology. It's appears after the request, the newly populated list isn't relating to the ui.sortable.js -- thanks

Comment: Is the snippet with sortable in index.php or the ajax page?

Comment: @Cranio the snippet with the sortable is in the ajax page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load script from a remote page using ajax, it is important to realize that the ready event has already occured in page you are loading into.

This means that code wrapped in `$(function(){})` will fire as soon as it is received. If that code preceeds the html it refers to, it will not find that html, as it doesn't exist yet.

If you move the same code below the html it refers to, it will fire after the html exists and therefore will find it.

**EDIT: My answer presumes that all the code shown after "Executes:" in OP is contained in remote page**

Comment: Nope. Ready is not fired until the DOM IS READY.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant.

Comment: (As per your edit: I *think* that he meant remote page too, but I am not sure)

Comment: @Cranio   both methods are valid and work fine...  you are slamming and downvoting  my response with a lot of your own assumptions. Got a better answer...pony up!

Comment: Uh, no. document.ready is still valid. Yes, the problem is with the ajax call, but this answer is incorrect in it's conclusion that the problem is related to this.

Comment: "User should use callback from starting page to do the job. " don't know what that means.

Comment: @charlietfl - you are correct the code after Execute is in the remote page.

Comment: @Bungdaddy  just switch positions of the script tag and html. Will work fine regardless of what all these noisemakers are saying

Comment: @Bungdaddy  if using repeatedly or if UL's are already sortable on initial page load, would only neeed to call sortable('refresh')

Comment: @charlietfl - still having issues with this one. It's after my modal closes: $('#albumFinished').click(function () { 
        tb_remove();
        //Load in the new images that were just uploaded     
        $('#sortableImages').load('../includes/sortImages.php?edit=' + edit);
    }); -- I lose the sortable() method

Comment: hard to help with limited info...post a link to a demo

Comment: @charlietfl - www.prophototweet.com - UN: demo@demo.com PW:stackoverflow -- there's a demo gallery link. At the bottom of the gallery details page, upload a revision. There is one revision there and will be sortable until you upload a new revision. If you save or refresh the page then the new revision will be sortable. Thanks a million for the help. ps you can upload any image type.

Comment: modal is loading jQuery again, which wipes out any plugins attached to original jQuery load (including jQueryUI). It seems to load quite a few scripts

Comment: Yeah it's a clean up job I acquired after some really "creative" fellas in Vietnam. I'll go through the modal and see what I can do.

Comment: @charlietfl - awesome man! I really appreciate the fresh eyes on that!!

Comment: this post still makes me laugh...2 guys slamming my answer, which worked out just as I said it would by rearanging load order of html/script

Comment: @Cranio  please note this indeed worked, so before you go downvoting, and slamming other answers...please do your homework and not vote based on incorrect assumptions

Comment: @charlietfl I've LONG (rpt: LONG) removed my downvote and deleted my wrong statement upon realizing I made a gross mistake. So what's your problem with me? It seems some other dude has not been honest like me in admitting his faults and taking actions to revert an incorrect judgement, so don't blame **me**.

Comment: @charlietfl **That said**, from a technical point of view, using `.ready()` in an AJAX call seems still a very unsafe solution, so I will not upvote until I make some more investigations. I assure my upvote if I find that this approach is safe and feasible in every scenario.

Comment: @Cranio  appreciate the retraction, my point was you've done this before...please don't be so quick to downvote and slam other answers without being able to support your statements.

Comment: @charlietfl My point was simple: I usually don't do it. I make my best efforts on research and self-improvement. Though, I *sometimes* make errors. My bad, I'm not perfect but I do learn lessons, and I do really appreciate your expertise. Don't assume that a downvote is always a deliberate act of pride of an ill-advised person, the tones seemed a bit too harsh. I hope that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have no handler for the result of the sort.php. Invoking this will only load the data into cache.

You need a complete handler function to refresh the data, not to mention add it to the dom. You should clarify your question and make it obvious that those are two different pages.

$.post("../albumUploader/queries/sort.php", order).complete = func...

Comment: my bad, thought the .load(../includes/sortImages.php?edit=' + edit) was clear that was another page, will definitely be more clear in future. Thanks for your answer. I'll have to look into implementing a complete handler.

Comment: @ FlavorScape  now that the code location has been clarifed, you can remove your downvote which was based on false assumptions on your part